# Package which inserts data to a table inserts wrong value (NULL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a package which inserts data to a table. However, there are few columns which the values that were inserted are NULL instead of an existing value based on the source table.

example:
Price.SourceTable
 - ColHours float
 - ColUnit varchar(10)
 - ColVolume float

Price.DestinationTable
 - ColHours int
 - ColUnit varchar(10)
 - ColVolume float

The values that I get in the destination table is NULL for the three columns.
however, there is one column (ColVolHours) which is a calculation from the 2 columns - ColHours * ColVolume - that has the actual value.

How is this possible that the ColVolHours has value whereas the 2 other columns were NULL?
And how can I know why the values inserted for the 3 columns were null?

Comment: you wil have to paste your package content here to know more about the problem

Comment: Assuming this is a SSIS issue, check the mapping at the destination are all correct. You can also setup Dataviewers along the paths to track the data changes.